# Different error messages while freeing allocated memory

Tags: c, memory, free, allocation

I created a struct, called ArrayCount, that contains a double array and an integer that should count how often an array occurs.

If the size of the double-array is n, the idea is, to create an array of the struct ArrayCount of the size n! (n! is called m in my code).

The idea is to safe each permutation in the ArrayCount-array, counting the occurrences of each permutation, for a given algorithm. But that's just the background information and not part of the problem.

I am having issues while freeing the memory that was allocated for the double-Arrays. 
Oddly enough, ~ 1/10 times my code compiles without an error message and sometimes different error messages appear.

1. error message:

   ```
   munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
   Aborted (core dumped)
   ```
2. error message:

   ```
   free(): invalid size
   Aborted (core dumped)
   ```
3. error message:

   ```
   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
   ```

Part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double* array_copy(const double* a, int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    double* copy = calloc(n, 8);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        copy[i] = a[i];
    }
    return copy;
}

void shuffle(double* a, int n) {
    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        time_t t;
        /* Intializes random number generator */
        srand((unsigned) time(&t));

        double* copy = array_copy(a, i + 1);
        //Generates random numbers in the closed intervall [0,i].
        int random = rand() % (i + 1);

        a[i] = a[random];
        a[random] = copy[i];

        free(copy);
    }
}

// Refers to a double array and counts how often this array has 
occurred yet.
typedef struct {
    double* array;
    int counter;
} ArrayCount;

// Computes the factorial of n: n!.
int factorial(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}

/*
Saves all permutations in array_counts, for a given double array of 
the length n and counts how often each permutations occurs.
(Hint given by our supervisor: Save a copy of a in array_counts)
*/
void update_array_counts(/*INOUT*/ ArrayCount* array_counts, int m, 
/*IN*/ const double* a, int n) {
    double* copy_a = array_copy(a, n);

    //Increases the counter by 1, if a is already listed in 
array_counts
for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(array_counts[i].array[j] == a[j]) count++;
    }
    if(count == n) {
        array_counts[i].counter++;
        free(copy_a);
        return;
    }
}

//Saves a in array_counts and sets the counter to 1, if a is not 
listed in array_counts, yet
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(array_counts[i].array[j] == 0) count++;
        }
        if(count == n) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                array_counts[i].array[j] = a[j];
            }
            array_counts[i].counter = 1;
            free(copy_a);
            return;
        }
    }   
}

// Gibt die Häufigkeit der verschiedenen Permutationen eines Arrays 
der Länge n aus.
void shuffle_frequency(int n) {
    double a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = i; 
    }
    int m = factorial(n);
    ArrayCount* array_counts = calloc(m, sizeof(ArrayCount));
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++){
        array_counts[i].array = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * m; i++) {
        shuffle(a, n);
        update_array_counts(array_counts, m, a, n);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        printf("%4d%8d    ", i, array_counts[i].counter);
    }
    //The next free-statement is causing problems.
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        free(array_counts[i].array);
    }

    free(array_counts);
}



int main(void) {
    shuffle_frequency(4);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a more *minimal* example that crashes in the same way?

Comment: Array indices start at `0`. If you allocate `m` element counts for `array_counts`, then you cannot access `array_counts[i]` with `i=m`.

Comment: Not related to your problem description: your usage of `srand()` is wrong. Put it in `main()`; don't call `srand()` inside a loop.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: `calloc(n, 8);` the magic number `8` looks suspicious.

Comment: `array_copy()` isn't useful; if you're swapping values of two indices, just save one in a temp `double` rather than copying the entire array. That will remove a minimum of 1000 calls to `calloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Like  https://stackoverflow.com/q/53875849/2410359

Comment: @SeanMonroe Thanks for that advice. Unfortunately it is asked in our problem definition to implement that function und the function rump was already given. So it should work that way, too.

Comment: @pmg Thanks, I will fix that. But that won't be part of the issue, because I actually used another method to generate the random numbers in my original code. But unfortunately I can't upload the library that I used to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having issues while freeing the memory that was allocated for the
>   double-Arrays. Oddly enough, ~ 1/10 times my code compiles without an
>   error message and sometimes different error messages appear.

*complies* without error message  or *runs* without error message?  I see runtime errors ( Segfault or Abort signals, to be exact ) not compile time.  kl

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
```

The correct way to iterate through an array of `m` elements is

```
 for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
```

As pointed out in the comments, offsets start at `0` and to to `m-1`, not `m`.   That makes `free(array_counts[i].array)`  becomes `free(array_counts[m].array)`  What's at `array_counts[m]`?  Could be various things, which might be deterministic or nondeterministic at runtime, but it is outside the memory you allocated.  Behavior of `free` is undefined in this case, as it is whenever passed an address that wasn't allocated with `malloc` and friends.

Consider http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html, a copy of the manpage for `free`:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
>          must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc(), or
>          realloc().  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called
>          before, undefined behavior occurs.